# How to render an internal PowerBI Report server report on an external app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, power-bi-report-server

I have few reports on an internal PowerBI Report Server(ON-PREMISE), which is required to be accessed on an external website. I can't use Iframe or Embed as MSFT mentioned, because I need to pass credentials and render on my external web app. If it was SSRS, I should have used ReportViewer controls or SSRS SOAP API to render, but in the case of ON-PREMISE PowerBI, I can't find any solution

I tried using HttpClient, WebClient to render the report, but its failing. Also tried SSRS ReportViewer object, which is also not working with PowerBI On-premise reports